# React Build Failed Compile Error: Unclosed comment at Array.every

Tags: css, reactjs, build, npm-run

I’m having a problem building my application on ReactJS, it is outputting this error:

```
     $ npm run build

> nannapp-web-app@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

static/css/main.ed463b24.css from Css Minimizer plugin
Error: Unclosed comment
    at Array.every (<anonymous>)
```

I can’t seem to find the comment it is referring, is there any way to get a detail on the error or file it referring to?

This is the index.html, i have added script tags to import Revolution Slider, as well as a bundled stylesheet:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <!-- <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" /> -->
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    
    
        <link href="dashboard/assets/css/style.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->


    <!-- Landing Page Scripts-->
    <script src="landing/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!--Revolution Slider-->
    <script src="landing/assets/plugins/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
    <script src="landing/assets/plugins/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
    <script src="landing/assets/plugins/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js"></script>
    <script src="landing/assets/plugins/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="landing/assets/plugins/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js"></script>
    <script src="landing/assets/plugins/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="landing/assets/plugins/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.migration.min.js"></script>
    <script src="landing/assets/plugins/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="landing/assets/plugins/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="landing/assets/plugins/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js"></script>
    <script src="landing/assets/plugins/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.video.min.js"></script>
    <script src="landing/assets/js/main-slider-script.js"></script>
    <!--Revolution Slider-->
    <script src="landing/assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="landing/assets/js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <script src="landing/assets/js/owl.js"></script>
    <script src="landing/assets/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
    <script src="landing/assets/js/wow.js"></script>
    <script src="landing/assets/js/appear.js"></script>
    <script src="landing/assets/js/script.js"></script>
    
        <script src="dashboard/assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js"></script>
        


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: Could you show us your code ?

Comment: Can you copy the full error message? I think there should be a log file that it writes to as well.